# Markup Formatting: Server-side or Client-side?

Tags: formatting, client-side, markup, server-side

I'm doing a project right now that might use a markup framework that I'll design specially for it, but which is the best way to do markup on the client-side or server-side for a startup service that might need to format big amounts of text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can do it on the server, do it on the server. This keeps the technological requirements on the client low (you usually do not have any control over the client).